# creating list of tuples from multiple vectors and constants

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

I have the following data:

```
m = 12
d = 10
ar1 = np.array([1,4,5,6])
type = [p,q,r,s] #same size as ar1
```

I want to create the following list of tuples:

```
[(12,10,1,p), (12,10,4,q), (12,10,5,r), (12,10,6,s)]
```

I tried using `zip` in various forms but I am not able to get the syntax right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` and a list comprehension:

```
[(m,d,x,y) for x,y in zip(ar1,type)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
the_tuple = [ (m, d, n[0], n[1]) for n in zip(ar1,type) ]
```